# jQuery Modal closes on third click

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am using jQuery modal plugin on my website. In most places the plugin works well, but at one or two places, when I click on the close button our outside of the modal it takes 2-3 clicks for some reason to close it.

I get this error 2 times after that the same action resolves into closing the modal:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fadeOut' of null
    at o.modal.unblock (jquery.modal.min.js:5)
    at o.modal.close (jquery.modal.min.js:5)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.o.modal.close (jquery.modal.min.js:5)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.trigger (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
```

Any suggestions of how to solve this?

Edit:

The modal closing is triggered by:

```js
$('#addressBookFrom .close-modal').trigger('click')
```

which is inside of onClick event

```js
body.on('click', '#addressBookTo .js-expand-parent', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault()

          // some logic ...

          $('#addressBookTo .close-modal').trigger('click')
        })
      })
```

Edit #2:

Ok so I figured it out. The problem was that each site had this function with following:

```js
smartex.modal = function () {
  $('a.modal-open').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).modal({
      fadeDuration: 200,
      closeExisting: false
    })
    $($(this).attr('href')).remove()
  })
}
```

Now if this function was invoked more than once you had to click for each time this function was invoked.

Comment: "Cannot read property 'fadeOut' of null" <= debug and find out why it's null

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: property 'fadeOut' of null that says the targeted element (to be faded out) is not recognized by jquery. As @j08691  told you, we need more clarification especially the jQuery function that handles modal closing where the fadeout() is being triggered.

Comment: Are those modals dynamically added (appended) by another script?

Comment: @j08691 I would love to, but sadly I don't know.I think that if I knew how to reproduce the problem I would know how to fix it.

It is app based on PHP framework (Nette) and its Templating system (Latte)

Comment: @Bilel no those are manually created in template

Comment: And there is no any other script interfering with this ... like another onClick handler ? :) not clear yet... The snippet you could reproduce here doesn't have to be using Latte' syntax. You can Inspect the rendered source and post it here as a snippet using the same HTML and used jQuery scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out. The problem was that each site had this function with following:

```js
smartex.modal = function () {
  $('a.modal-open').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).modal({
      fadeDuration: 200,
      closeExisting: false
    })
    $($(this).attr('href')).remove()
  })
}
```

Now if this function was invoked more than once you had to click for each time this function was invoked.